# Django request_finished signal

Tags: django

How to use **request_started** signal in django?
I want to execute some commands before processing a http request or do django have a callback similar with **rails before_filter**?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Consider [writing your own middleware](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware) instead.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/) you may use:

```
from django.core.signals import request_finished
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(request_finished)
def my_callback(sender, **kwargs):
    # process
```